# Product of first n terms in a sequence in python

Tags: python, sequence, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to create a function that takes one argument (a number) and returns the factorial of that number.

For example f(5) will return 1*2*3*4*5

What I have so far is

```
def product(n, term):
    """Return the product of the first n terms in a sequence.

    term -- a function that takes one argument
    """
    k, total = 1, 1
    while k <= n:
        k, total = k + 1, total * term(k, 1)
    return total


def factorial(n):
    """Return n factorial by calling product.

    >>> factorial(4)
    24
    """
    return product(n, mul)
```

However, is it possible to make it so that term only takes 1 argument?

Comment: "term only takes 1 argument?"  What is `mul` in your example?  If `mul` means "multiply", then how can it work with one argument?  Don't you mean `term(total,k)` instead of `total * term(k,1)`?  What are you trying to do?  Can you write a more detailed explanation of how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

def factorial(n):
    return math.factorial(n)
```

Alternative implementation:

```
def factorial(n):
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,range(1,n+1))
```

Using recursion:

```
def factorial(n):
     if n == 0:
         return 1
     else:
         return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without calling factorial?

Comment: because i need to use product() later for another function

Comment: Note for Python 3.0, `reduce` has been moved to the functools package.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the factorial of n is a standard example of a recursive function:

```
def fac(n):
    return n * fac(n-1) if n > 1 else 1
```

Comment: It may be a standard example, but I've never liked it, using recursion when a simple iterating loop would be just as good, and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

What about?

```
import operator

def product(nums):
    return reduce(operator.mul, nums, 1)

def factorial(num):
    return product(range(2, num+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

if what you mean is that in `product(n, term)`, `term(n)` should be a function from an index `n` in series to the value at that point; then your `factorial(n)` would be defined as `def factorial(n): return product(n, identity)` where identity is `def identity(n): return n`

in other words:

```
def product(n, term):
    """Return the product of the first n terms in a sequence.

    term -- a function that takes one argument
    """
    k, total = 1, 1
    while k <= n:
        k, total = k + 1, total * term(k)
    return total


def identity(n):
    return n

def factorial(n):
    """Return n factorial by calling product.

    >>> factorial(4)
    24
    """
    return product(n, identity)
```